# Convertion of string in numeric by multiplication operator

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I'd like to convert a string in numeric by multiplication operator. In my data frame `mydf` a have a column `ESPAC` and my ideas is the conversion of the first row, for example: "2.70x2.20" to 5.9 using an operation of `2.70*2.20`. Is there a simple way to make it? My desirable final output is `mydf2`:

```
ID<-1:9
ESPAC<-c("2.70x2.20","3.5X2","3.6X2","3.00x1.33","3.00x2.00","3.00x2.50","3.00x3.00","3.5x2.14","3.90x2.32")
mydf<-data.frame(ID,ESPAC)
mydf
#  ID     ESPAC
#1  1 2.70x2.20
#2  2     3.5X2
#3  3     3.6X2
#4  4 3.00x1.33
#5  5 3.00x2.00
#6  6 3.00x2.50
#7  7 3.00x3.00
#8  8  3.5x2.14
#9  9 3.90x2.32

mydf2
#  ID     ESPAC
#1  1      5.9
#2  2      7.0
# ...
#9  9      9.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### base R

```r
mydf$res <- sapply(strsplit(mydf$ESPAC, "[Xx]"), function(z) prod(as.numeric(z)))
mydf
#   ID     ESPAC   res
# 1  1 2.70x2.20 5.940
# 2  2     3.5X2 7.000
# 3  3     3.6X2 7.200
# 4  4 3.00x1.33 3.990
# 5  5 3.00x2.00 6.000
# 6  6 3.00x2.50 7.500
# 7  7 3.00x3.00 9.000
# 8  8  3.5x2.14 7.490
# 9  9 3.90x2.32 9.048
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  mutate(res = sapply(strsplit(ESPAC, "[Xx]"), function(z) prod(as.numeric(z))))
#   ID     ESPAC   res
# 1  1 2.70x2.20 5.940
# 2  2     3.5X2 7.000
# 3  3     3.6X2 7.200
# 4  4 3.00x1.33 3.990
# 5  5 3.00x2.00 6.000
# 6  6 3.00x2.50 7.500
# 7  7 3.00x3.00 9.000
# 8  8  3.5x2.14 7.490
# 9  9 3.90x2.32 9.048
```

---

Data

```r
mydf <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, ESPAC = c("2.70x2.20", "3.5X2", "3.6X2", "3.00x1.33", "3.00x2.00", "3.00x2.50", "3.00x3.00", "3.5x2.14", "3.90x2.32"), res = c(5.94, 7, 7.2, 3.99, 6, 7.5, 9, 7.49, 9.048)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `eval`, `parse`, `text` after replacing `x` with `*`.

```
mydf$ESPAC <- sapply(gsub('x', '*', mydf$ESPAC, ignore.case = TRUE), 
                     function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
mydf

#  ID ESPAC
#1  1 5.940
#2  2 7.000
#3  3 7.200
#4  4 3.990
#5  5 6.000
#6  6 7.500
#7  7 9.000
#8  8 7.490
#9  9 9.048
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in `vectorized` way

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mydf %>% 
   separate(ESPAC, into = c('res', 'res2'), sep="[xX]", 
      convert = TRUE, remove = FALSE) %>% 
   mutate(res = res * res2, res2 = NULL)
  ID     ESPAC   res
1  1 2.70x2.20 5.940
2  2     3.5X2 7.000
3  3     3.6X2 7.200
4  4 3.00x1.33 3.990
5  5 3.00x2.00 6.000
6  6 3.00x2.50 7.500
7  7 3.00x3.00 9.000
8  8  3.5x2.14 7.490
9  9 3.90x2.32 9.048
```

---

Or using `base R` with `read.table`

```
mydf$res <- Reduce(`*`, read.table(text = sub("x", "X", mydf$ESPAC), 
        header = FALSE, sep="X"))
```

#### data

```
mydf <- structure(list(ID = 1:9, ESPAC = c("2.70x2.20", "3.5X2", "3.6X2", 
"3.00x1.33", "3.00x2.00", "3.00x2.50", "3.00x3.00", "3.5x2.14", 
"3.90x2.32"), res = c(5.94, 7, 7.2, 3.99, 6, 7.5, 9, 7.49, 9.048
)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```